# Check if a file exists in directory

Tags: c#, console

I am making an C# setup program that first checks for Terminal. However when I use `File.Exists()` it always returns false.

Is there a solution for this problem?

Code (minimal):

```
if (File.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe"))
{
    WriteAtPosition(0, 29, "you have terminal! (gg)");
}
else
{
    WriteAtPosition(0, 29, "you no have terminal. (rip you)");
}
```

Code (full):

`````
Console.Write("\u001b[48;2;255;255;255m\u001b[38;2;40;155;204m");
Console.WriteLine("      ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒███████▒▒▒██▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█████████████████████████████████████▒█▒▒▒███████████████████████████████████████");
Console.WriteLine("       ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒█████████████████████████████████▒▒▒▒▒▒████████████████████████████████████████");
Console.WriteLine("        ░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒███████████████████████▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒████████████████████████████████████████");
Console.WriteLine("         ░▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░````           ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒█████▒██████████████▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒████████▒▒███████████████████████████");
Console.WriteLine("          ░░░░░░                     ░░░░░░░░░  '░░▒▒▒█▒▒▒██████████████▒░░    ░░░░▒▒████▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒████████████████████");
Console.WriteLine("            `                        ░░░  ░░░░░    ░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒███████████▒▒░░░░    ░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░▒▒▒▒▒█████████████████████");
Console.WriteLine("                                      ░░░''░░░░     ░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒██████████▒▒▒▒▒░░░  ░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒░▒▒▒██████████████████████");
Console.WriteLine("                                                     ░░░░░░▒▒▒▒████████▒▒▒▒░░`    ░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒████████████████████████");
Console.WriteLine("                                                       ```░░░▒▒██▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░    ░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█████████████████████████");
Console.WriteLine("░░                                                         ░░▒▒█▒▒░░░░░░░░    ░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒█████████████████████▒▒▒▒▒▒");
Console.WriteLine("░░░░░                                    ░░░              ░▒▒███▒▒▒░        ░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒███████████████▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒");
Console.WriteLine("░░░░░░                                 ░░▒▒▒░░░░         ░▒▒▒███▒▒░░         ░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒██████▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒");
Console.WriteLine("░░░░░░░                               ░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░   .░▒▒▒██████▒░░      ░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒░░▒▒▒░▒▒▒▒████████▒▒▒▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒");
Console.WriteLine(" '░░░░░                               ░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒███████████@▒▒▒░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█████████▒▒▒▒░░░░░░▒▒▒");
Console.WriteLine("                                  ░░░░░░ '░▒▒▒▒▒███████████████████████▒▒▒░░▒▒▒▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒█████████▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░▒▒▒");
Console.WriteLine("░       ░░░░░░                    ░░'     ░▒▒▒▒▒▒██████████████████████▒▒▒░▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒██████▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒");
Console.WriteLine("░░      ░░░░░░░░                            ░▒▒▒▒▒▒█████████████████████▒▒▒▒▒▒██▒▒▒▒▒▒██████▒▒▒▒▒▒████████▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒");
Console.WriteLine("░░░      ░░░░░░░░                             ░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒██████████████████████████████████████▒████████████████████████▒▒");
Console.WriteLine("░░░      ░░░░░░░                                 '░░▒░░▒▒█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▒▒");
Console.WriteLine("░░░                                               ░░░░░░░▒██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████▒▒▒▒");
Console.WriteLine("░                  ░░░                               ░░░░▒▒▒▒██▒█████████████████████████████████████████████████▒▒▒▒▒▒▒");
Console.WriteLine("░            ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░             ░░░░░▒▒████▒▒▒▒▒▒███████████████████████████████████████████▒▒▒▒▒▒▒");
Console.WriteLine("░░░ ░░░    ░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░    ░  ░ ░░░░▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒████████████████████████████████▒▒▒▒▒▒");
Console.WriteLine("░░     ░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒███████████████████████████████████");
Console.WriteLine("░      ░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒██████████████████████████████▒▒▒");
Console.WriteLine("░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒░░░░░░░▒▒░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒██▒▒▒▒▒███████████████████████████");
Console.WriteLine("░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░░░▒▒▒▒░▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒░░░░▒▒▒▒▒█████████████████████████████████");
Console.Write("\u001b[48;2;0;0;0m\u001b[38;2;255;255;255m");
// WriteAtPosition(0, 28, "████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████");
WriteAtPosition(0, 28, "██");
WriteAtPosition(0, 29, "Checking for Terminal...");
if (File.Exists(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe"))
{
    WriteAtPosition(0, 29, "you have terminal! (gg)");
}
else
{
    WriteAtPosition(0, 29, "you no have terminal. (rip you)");
}
Thread.Sleep(10000);
static void WriteAtPosition(int left, int top, string text)
{
    Console.CursorLeft = left;
    Console.CursorTop = top;

    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
`````

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because that file doesn't exist, at least at the path you specified.
`Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` returns the absolute path to the current directory so appending `@"%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe"` to that path doesn't make sense.

You just want to test if the file exists in your LocalAppData path. `File.Exists` doesn't work if you try to use that path however (it doesn't understand the `%LocalAppData%` wildcards), so you must first get the location of `%LocalAppData%` with `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)` then concat the rest of the path you are looking for like so

```
File.Exists(@$"{Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData)}\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe")
```

or better

```
Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(
Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), @"\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\wt.exe");
```